# Вывод на экран с помощью Sprite

Tags: java, libgdx

Начал писать игру на фреймворке `libgdx`. И сразу же столкнулся с проблемой - не могу вывести кусок/регион/спрайт из атласа. 
- сделал атлас (512х512, заполнен не полностью графикой)
- написал следующий код

```
Texture atlas;
TextureRegion regionHero;
Sprite spriteHero;
SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void create () {
    atlas = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("graphic/TextureAtlas3.png"));
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    spriteHero = new Sprite(atlas, 0, 128, 64, 64);
    spriteHero.setPosition(0, 0);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    spriteHero.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}

public void resize (int width, int height) { }

public void pause () { }

public void resume () { }

public void dispose () {
    super.dispose();
    atlas.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
}
```

Запускаю на desktop, а мне то пустоту выводит, то не ту картинку.
Атлас (нижние левые углы картинок):

- пустота, но в будущем планирую добавить еще графики (размеры: 64х64)
- (0;128),(64;128)
- (0;64), (64;64),(128;64),...(448;64)
- (0;0) , (64;0), (128;0)

Я не правильно задаю Spite или в чем может быть ошибка ?

Answer (score 1):

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas......
```